# Connection to MongoDB in Azure with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, azure

first: i'm new at azure. Ok, I want a MongoDb replica set in azure. I used for it these websites:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Azure+Deployment and
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure
Thats works fine. But how can I access from my java application to this mongo replicaset? The java application doesn't run in the cloud.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

A few things you could do:

- Run mongos (shard router) on your replicaset nodes, and create a single shard representing the entire database. Mongos would have internal visibility to the ip/port for each replicaset node. Then, your external java app would connect directly to mongos. Note: The use of mongos is not part of the scaffolding project 10gen provides. You'd need to add this yourself.
- Set up Azure Connect, to bridge between your Java app and your MongoDB replicaset deployment. There's an --ipv6 flag you'd need to add to the command line of mongod (as Azure Connect only supports ipv6 traffic over the tunnel). I can't recall if this flag is set in the 10gen-provided scaffolding, and ipv6 is disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

By default MongoDB will run on port 27017 (see [TCP Port Numbers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes)). Simply create an [Input Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433020.aspx) to allow your on-premise java application to connect to MongoDB and make sure you choose **tcp** as protocol.

This is a screenshot of such an endpoint from [David's blog](http://www.davidmakogon.com/2011/02/azure-tip-overload-your-web-role-for.html):

[image: MongoDB]

Remember that this will open the port for everyone on the internet, which could be a security risk.

Alternatively, you might consider using [Windows Azure Connect](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-network/) to create a secure IPSEC connection between your on-premise system and your roles.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for a replicaset, as the client application needs to enumerate all replicaset nodes to create the set configuration, and you cannot enumerate instances through the Windows Azure load balancer. This *would* work for a standalone version of MongoDB, but then you'd also likely want to rebuild MongoDB from source, to include SSL (since that's not included in the distribution binaries). And... then you'd need to enable security as well.

Comment: Having said that: Thanks for the blog post shout-out. :)

Comment: +1 for the Windows Azure Connect suggestion - I didn't see that the first time I read it.

Comment: Thank you for help. It's correct, it doesn't work with replica sets. If I start MongoDb without replica sets it will be work.
Now I will test the idea from Mr. Makogon.