# Hosting MongoDB on Windows Azure for C# Access

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

I have read this page: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Azure+Deployment, but it seems to be talking about actually setting up an Azure application, which I'm not interested in. I just want to host a Mongo DB on Azure which I can access from some non-Azure application using a connection string. I also tried running the script on this page: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Installer+for+Windows+Azure but it threw an exception when it tried to validate the image name. Is what I want possible?

The reason for all of this is that I'm trying to compare MongoDB and Azure Table Storage, and I want to make the scenarios as similar as possible when I performance test.

Answer (score 3):

The first link in your question talks about deploying MongoDB in Windows Azure (also accessible by other applications), but this in a traditional PaaS context. This means you'll be deploying MongoDB in a hosted service/cloud service.

If you want to host MongoDB on Windows Azure in a way that "feels more natural" you should consider deploying it in a Virtual Machine (the second link in your question). There's actually a how to on the Windows Azure website that will guide you through the whole process of creating a VM and deploying MongoDB on that VM: [Install MongoDB on a virtual machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-mongodb/)

Both ways to deploy MongoDB will allow you to access it from non-Azure applications, you'll simply need to configure the endpoints correctly (allowing access to specific ports from outside the datacenter).

Note that Virtual Machines (IaaS) is still a preview feature and the performance in the preview might not reflect the performance of the final version.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I have to deploy a whole application, since I am prevented from creating VMs. How do I go about configuring the endpoints to make the DB accessible from non-Azure applications?

Comment: This depends if you want to run a replicaset or the standalone version. Take a look at the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583747/connection-to-mongodb-in-azure-with-java. And just a small note for the VMs, you should be able to use VMs, but only after signing up for the preview.

Comment: Is there any way to use the public port method with a replica set? It seems like a fair amount of work to set up mongos.

Answer (score 0):

You can run MongoDB on Windows Azure two ways. First way is to run as Cloud Service which is described [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Azure+Deployment) however this is not what you want.

The second option to run MongoDB on Windows Azure to use Windows Azure Virtual Machine (either Linux or Windows) and then install MongoDB on it. The link below explains how you can install MongoDB on a CentOS machine in Windows Azure:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/mongodb-on-a-linux-vm/

If you decide to use Windows Virtual Machine, you sure can use any MongoDB tutorial to install it on Windows box after configuring Windows Virtual Machine or just [use this one](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-mongodb/).

As you have already tried [using Powershell to deploy MongoDB from your desktop to Windows VM](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Installer+for+Windows+Azure), but failed to get working, please write another question with error details and i sure can help.

Finally based on your actual objective I would suggest creating MongoDB on CentOS by following above tutorial and get your test done, which could be easiest MongoDB setup among all the methods we have talked.

Comment: I'm coming to realize now as I'm trying to set up the VM that there may be a more fundamental access issue I'm having that's preventing me from setting up a VM in any way. I'm looking into that and if I still get the script error afterward I will open another question.